# Скрыть блок tr в таблице по клику?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr><td>title 1</td></tr>
    <tr class="hidcont"><td>content 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>title 2</td></tr>
    <tr class="hidcont"><td>content 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>title 3</td></tr>
    <tr class="hidcont"><td>content 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Ничего особенного, табличка как табличка, скрипт `jQuery`:

```
$('tr').click(function(){

    var hidcont = $(this).next('tr');

    if (hidcont.hasClass('hidcont')){

        $('.hidcont').hide();

        $(this).next('tr').toggle();

    }
});
```

Открывает/Скрывает блоки. Тоже ничего такого. А проблемка в следующем:  хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на `tr` скрывался/открывался текущий открытый блок с контентом, а то сейчас выходит так, что туглит скрытый элемент и в итоге текущий блок с контентом остается видимым.

В общем, все это лучше 1 раз увидеть, чем 1 раз услышать [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/CAQxQ/)

**upd** (решение)

```
$('tr').click(function(){

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

        $('.hidcont').hide();

        $(this).removeClass('active');

    }
    else
    {

        $('.active').next('.hidcont').hide();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).next('.hidcont').show();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Так](http://jsfiddle.net/oneboy/CAQxQ/12/) ? Или я неправильно понял вопрос...

Comment: В вашем случае можно ограничится [вот так ](http://jsfiddle.net/CAQxQ/13/)

Comment: нет, все не то, дело в том что я хочу ограничиться лишь одним открытым блоком!

Comment: ладно, сам решил (см. upd).